# unit test for service layer when using springboot ebean

Tags: unit-testing, orm, ebean

env:Springboot ebean as orm
service layer code like below

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserInfoServiceImpl implements UserInfoService {

    private final UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    private final UserInfoMapper userInfoMapper;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserInfoDTO save(UserInfoDTO userInfoDto) {
        UserInfo entity = convertToEntity(userInfoDto);
        entity.save();
        return convertToDTO(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public UserInfoDTO findById(Long userId) {
        return convertToDTO(UserInfo.find.byId(userId));
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserInfoDTO update(UserInfoDTO userInfoDto) {
        UserInfo userInfo = convertToEntity(userInfoDto);
        userInfo.update();
        return convertToDTO(userInfo);
    }

    public UserInfoDTO convertToDTO(UserInfo userInfo) {
        return userInfoMapper.toDTO(userInfo);
    }

    public UserInfo convertToEntity(UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO) {
        return userInfoMapper.toEntity(userInfoDTO);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(Long userId) {
        UserInfo.find.deleteById(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserInfoDTO> list() {
        List<UserInfo> all = UserInfo.find.all();
        return userInfoMapper.toDTOList(all);
    }
}
```

question 1:
how to write an unit test for active record (means the save method)
question 2:
how to write the unit test for findById, update,delete
thanks

or maybe we don't need write a unit test for such kind of method

Thanks very much

the whole project could be found here  [github](https://github.com/Johnson0125/douding/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/doubao/douding/system/service/impl/UserInfoServiceImpl.java)

some help link for ebean-mock
[ebean-mock](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean-mocker/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/EbeanServerMockTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

for question 2, I found a solution here
when wanna mock a static final field in java 17 or above, you can use the code below

```
    Field field = UserInfo.class.getField("find");
    final Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
    final Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);

    final Field ourField = UserInfo.class.getDeclaredField("find");
    final Object staticFieldBase = unsafe.staticFieldBase(ourField);
    final long staticFieldOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(ourField);
    unsafe.putObject(staticFieldBase, staticFieldOffset, userInfoFinder);
```

here is the reference link [help link](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)